# TeamCity: urllib2.HTTPError: HTTP Error 401: Unauthorized

Tags: python, python-2.7, teamcity, urllib2

Wrote a script to cancel old builds running on TeamCity. I'm able to list the all running builds based as per my requirement(buildTypeId,branchName).I need to send a REST API call to cancel old build, this request is throwing 401 error. I guess misusing the POST method using urllib2. Anyone can help me on this please?

```
import urllib2
import re
from xml.dom import minidom
url = 'https://<TeamCity>/httpAuth/app/rest/builds?locator=running:true'
username = user_name
password = password
p = urllib2.HTTPPasswordMgrWithDefaultRealm()
p.add_password(None, url, username, password)
handler = urllib2.HTTPBasicAuthHandler(p)
opener = urllib2.build_opener(handler)
urllib2.install_opener(opener)
dom = minidom.parse(urllib2.urlopen(url))
build = dom.getElementsByTagName('build')

for i in range(0, len(build)):
    for j in range(i+1, len(build)):
        find_build_type = re.search(r'<Job_1>.*', build[i].getAttribute("buildTypeId"), re.M | re.I)
        if build[i].getAttribute("branchName") != '<default>' and find_build_type:
            if (build[i].getAttribute("buildTypeId") == build[j].getAttribute("buildTypeId") and build[i].getAttribute("branchName") == build[j].getAttribute("branchName")):
                #Get the old build
                old_run = "https://<TeamCity>/app/rest/buildQueue/id:" + str(min(int(build[j].getAttribute("id")),int(build[i].getAttribute("id"))))
                #headers
                headers={"Content-Type": "application/xml"}
                #data
                passman = urllib2.HTTPPasswordMgrWithDefaultRealm()
                passman.add_password(None, url, username, password)
                opener = urllib2.build_opener(urllib2.HTTPBasicAuthHandler(passman))
                urllib2.install_opener(opener)
                r = urllib2.Request(old_run, data, headers)
                #send API request to cancel the old build
                u = urllib2.urlopen(r)
```

Comment: I don't think that url is valid

Comment: @whackamadoodle3000 both two url's are valid url old_run. I verified both the url's.